# Trouble with sorting 2d double array alongside 1d string array.

Tags: c++, sorting, multidimensional-array

This is a working program that I've been trying to learn C++ from that inputs from a file strings and doubles and puts them into their perspective arrays. What I'm stuck on is while sorting the strings I want to sort the array of doubles in ascending order and keep the scores with the name they are associated with. I'm trying to learn it without using vectors before I go on to learn how to manipulate them, that's the reason for not using vectors before anyone asks. 
Is it best to sort the columns of the 2d array and than sort them with the 1d array or just to have a statement that does it all? Also what would be the best sorting algorithm for this application? 
My attempts have all failed so far so I turn to the community here for help. The logic is most likely some simple concept that I have yet to grasp. We all have to start somewhere. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;  

void ArraySort (string x[], double y[][3], int length);

int main() 
{
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("bowlers2.txt");

    const int SIZE = 10;

    int i,j;
    double scores[10][3];
    string names[SIZE];
    string mystring;

    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Can not open the input file"
             << " This program will end."<< "\n";
        return 1;

    }

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        getline(inFile, names[i]);
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            getline(inFile, mystring);
            scores[i][j] = atoi(mystring.c_str());
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        cout << names[i] << "\n";
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << scores[i][j] << "\n";
    }

    inFile.close();

    ArraySort (names, scores, SIZE);

    return 0;
}

void ArraySort (string x[], double y[][3], int LENGTH)
{
    int i,j;
    string sValue;
    double dValue;

    for(i = 1; i < LENGTH; i++)
    {
        sValue = x[i];
        for(j = i - 1; j >= 0 && x[j] > sValue; j--)
        {
            x[j + 1] = x[j]; 
        }
        x[j + 1] = sValue;
    }

    cout << "\n";
    for(int i=0;i<LENGTH;i++)
    {
        cout << x[i] << "\n";
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << y[i][j] << "\n";
    }

}
```

file read by program:

```
Linus too good
100
23
210
Charlie brown
1
2
12
Snoopy
300
300
100
Peperment Patty
223
300
221
Pig Pen
234
123
212
Red Headed Girl
123
222
111
Marcey
1
2
3
keith hallmark
222
300
180
anna hallmark
222
111
211
roxie hallmark
100
100
2
```

Comment: I advise you to reorder the sets of numbers and sort the numbers within the sets in *two independent operations.* Try that, and tell us which operation you need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you’re trying to do is this:

```
void ArraySort (string x[], double y[][3], int LENGTH)
{
    int i,j,k;
    string sValue;
    double dValue;
    double dArray[3];

    for(i = 1; i < LENGTH; i++)
    {
        sValue = x[i];
        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
           dArray[k] = y[i][k];
        }
        for(j = i - 1; j >= 0 && x[j] > sValue; j--)
        {
            x[j + 1] = x[j];
            for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
               y[j + 1][k] = y[j][k];
            }
        }
        x[j + 1] = sValue;
        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
           y[j + 1][k] = dArray[k];
        }
    }

    for(k = 0; k < LENGTH; k++)
        for(i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        {
            dValue = y[k][i];
            for(j = i - 1; j >= 0 && y[k][j] > dValue; j--)
            {
                y[k][j + 1] = y[k][j]; 
            }
            y[k][j + 1] = dValue;
        }
    }

    cout << "\n";
    for(int i=0;i<LENGTH;i++)
    {
        cout << x[i] << "\n";
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << y[i][j] << "\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: That solves my dilemma. After seeing this work I now understand better where my logical errors were coming from. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mrbw My pleasure. Note also that it doesn’t matter which of the two sorting algorithms comes first.

Answer (score 1):

For learning purposes you can use bubble sort. Bubble sort is very easy, also very inefficient and slow. In a real application you would use `std::sort`

```
template <typename T> 
void bubble_sort(T *num, int num_count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (num_count - 1); i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < num_count; j++)
            if (num[i] > num[j])
                std::swap(num[i], num[j]);
}

void ArraySort(string str[], double num[][3], int str_count)
{
    int num_count = 3;
    bubble_sort(str, str_count);

    for (int i = 0; i < str_count; i++)
        bubble_sort(num[i], num_count);

    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < str_count; i++)
    {
        cout << str[i] << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < num_count; j++)
            cout << num[i][j] << "\n";
    }
}
```